# Jenkins build failure with SVNException (Processing REPORT request response failed)

Tags: jenkins

I setup Jenkins to auto-build a project controled by SVN. I encountered an issue, the project checkout failure.

I didn't encounter the issue always. Actually, I only encounter it once.

Could you give me some guidence about the root cause of the issue? How could I avoid the issue happens again. Thank you:-)

The exception is below:

```
    Failed to check out http://ziyue.corp.com/svn/repos/process_tools/trunk/stevsssion
    org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: REPORT /svn/repos/process_tools/!svn/vcc/default failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:298)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:283)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:271)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:283)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1282)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:830)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.update(SVNUpdateClient.java:564)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:942)
        at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:84)
        at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:136)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:788)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:769)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:753)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:743)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:685)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1342)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout        (AbstractBuild.java:683)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:588)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1568)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
    Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: REPORT /svn/repos/process_tools/!svn/vcc/default failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:146)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:89)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/repos/process_tools/!svn/vcc/default'
    svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: The element type "S:prop" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</S:prop>". (/svn/repos/process_tools/!svn/vcc/default) 
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:662)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:292)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/repos/process_tools/!svn/vcc/default'
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:660)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: The element type "S:prop" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</S:prop>". (/svn/repos/process_tools/!svn/vcc/default) 
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:181)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:133)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:790)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:741)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:218)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:379)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: No, it's strange issue. I only encounterd the issue once.